# Flutter usb_serial package

Tags: flutter, serial-port

I want to send hex format data in the usb_serial flutter package for serial communication with RS232? does anyone have an idea about how to send hex command

Answer (score 0):

Here's a flutter plugin for serial communication on a pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/serial_communication

When opening the port you can choose the data format
For ASCII format:

```
serialCommunication.openPort(
dataFormat: DataFormat.ASCII,
serialPort: serialList.first,
baudRate: serialCommunication.baudRateList.first)
```

For HEX format:

```
serialCommunication.openPort(
dataFormat: DataFormat.HEX_STRING,
serialPort: serialList.first,
baudRate: serialCommunication.baudRateList.first)
```